# Java Nashorn equivalent of pushing object to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, object, nashorn

In Javascript I would like to iterate through something, create an object for each iteration, set some values, and push that to an array.

```
var arr = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.id = d.id;
    obj.value = d.value;
    arr.push(obj);
 })
```

How do I accomplish this in Nashorn?

I have tried

```
var ArrayList = Java.type("java.util.ArrayList");
var list = new ArrayList();

 list.add(obj)
```

type of approach though I am not getting the values back out?

Comment: I dont think I understand the question. you mean using java api through nashhorn right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Dont think I fully understand the question but asuming you are refering to adding a javascript object to a Java ArrayList from Nashhorn you can do the following.

```
jjs> var myList = Java.type('java.util.ArrayList');
jjs> var list = new myList();
jjs> list.add({a:1})
true
jjs> list.get(0).a
1
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yeah I suppose somehow it wasn't sending the print through the server to log properly. this is what I was attempting with the above. alright thanks.